# Unable to use composite key as foreign key

Tags: oracle

```
CREATE TABLE departments
( department_id number(10) NOT NULL,
  department_name varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
  department_code varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT departments_pk PRIMARY KEY (department_id, department_code)
);

CREATE TABLE employees
( employee_number number(10) NOT NULL,
  employee_name varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
  department_id number(10),
  salary number(6),
  CONSTRAINT employees_pk PRIMARY KEY (employee_number),
  CONSTRAINT fk_departments
    FOREIGN KEY (department_id, department_code)
    REFERENCES departments(department_id,department_code));
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: When i am executing, i am getting: Error at Command Line:17 Column:32
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "DEPARTMENT_CODE": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `employees` table doesn't have a `department_code` field, so the `FOREIGN KEY (department_id, department_code)` part is trying to use something that doesn't exist. Which is what the error you get from running the second statement tells you:

```
ERROR at line 8:
ORA-00904: "DEPARTMENT_CODE": invalid identifier
```

You would either have to include the department code in that table, which would denormalise the data; or change the primary key on `departments` to just `department_id`, which would be much more normal anyway, i.e.:

```
CREATE TABLE departments
( department_id number(10) NOT NULL,
  department_name varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
  department_code varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT departments_pk PRIMARY KEY (department_id)
);

CREATE TABLE employees
( employee_number number(10) NOT NULL,
  employee_name varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
  department_id number(10),
  salary number(6),
  CONSTRAINT employees_pk PRIMARY KEY (employee_number),
  CONSTRAINT fk_departments
    FOREIGN KEY (department_id)
    REFERENCES departments(department_id));
```

It doesn't usually make sense to have a composite primary key like that, where there is a single column that looks like it should be unique anyway. You wouldn't expect to have the same `department_id` with two `department_code` values.

But if you do have a legitimate reason to have a composite primary key then all columns in that key will have to be duplicated on the child tables and their foreign key constraints:

```
CREATE TABLE employees
( employee_number number(10) NOT NULL,
  employee_name varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
  department_id number(10),
  department_code varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
  salary number(6),
  CONSTRAINT employees_pk PRIMARY KEY (employee_number),
  CONSTRAINT fk_departments
    FOREIGN KEY (department_id, department_code)
    REFERENCES departments(department_id,department_code));

Table EMPLOYEES created.
```

Which means that whenever you insert a record into that table you will have to supply both the ID and code for an existing department, of course.

Comment: I am working on a application which is already created. So departments table is already there. So i cannot change the primary key for that because of data integrity. so i ve to use that only as foreign key.

Comment: So you have to add the department code to the employees table then. Changing the department table's primary key would only affect integrity if you already have duplicate IDs, with different codes, really.

Comment: even i am unable to add department_id as foreign key.

Comment: @PRINCEGUPTA - you mean a foreign key with *just* the ID? No, because there is no primary (or unique) key with just that column. You have to work with the primary key that is there, which means you have to add the department code column to the employees table. (Or change the PK; or add a separate unique key to the departments table, which won't work if there are duplicate IDs with different codes - and if there are not then the composite PK doesn't make sense).

Comment: Is there any way to make composite key of one table as a foreign key of another table?

Comment: @PRINCEGUPTA - yes, you have all columns from the composite PK in the child table. That's what I've shown.